# Using for loops and switch cases in React to dynamically render different components

Tags: loops, switch-statement, reactjs

I am trying to render components conditionally using switch case in React JSX. I am trying to build something that reads from a specific json structure and renders the data. Since there can be many different components and data, I am trying to render it dynamically. See my code below, I am not getting any errors but the components aren't getting rendered. Inside my html , I can only see  . This means the loop isn't working. I tried using the same loop in vanilla JS and it works.

```
var myPackage = [{
    sectionInfo:[{
        elementType: 1,
        text: "This is text from element type 1"
    }]
},
{
    sectionInfo:[{
        elementType: 2,
        text: "This is text from element type 2"
    }]
}];
var App = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
        var elements = [];
        elements = myPackage.map(function(myObj){
            myObj.sectionInfo.map(function(myObj1){
                switch(myObj1.elementType){
                    case 1: return(
                                <Component1 text = {myObj1.text}/>
                            );
                            break;
                    case 2: return(
                                <Component2 text = {myObj1.text}/>
                            )
                            break;      
                }
            })
        });
        return(
            <div className="App">
                {elements}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
var Component1 = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div className = "element1">
                {this.props.text}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
var Component2 = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div className = "element2">
                {this.props.text}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('container'));
```

Edit: Made a few additions to the code, and now I am facing a new problem. Here is the new code:

```
var App = React.createClass({

        render: function(){
            var elements = [];
            elements = myPackage.map(function(myObj){
                return(
                       <div>
                           myObj.sectionInfo.map(function(myObj1){
                           switch(myObj1.elementType){
                           case 1: return(
                                    <Component1 text = {myObj1.text}/>
                                );
                                break;
                           case 2: return(
                                    <Component2 text = {myObj1.text}/>
                                )
                                break;      
                        }
                        }
                  </div>
                )
                });
        return(
            <div className="App">
                {elements}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

I want to render each time inside a div. So that if one section has more than 3 elements, then all 3 must be inside a div.

Comment: `elements` is a list of lists but should be list of components. Try to flatten it with `elements = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], elements)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should return value from first `.map`, in your case it is result from inner `.map`

```
var elements = myPackage.map(function(myObj){
  return myObj.sectionInfo.map(function(myObj1) {
     // ...  
  });
});
```

**Update:**

Based on your new update, you can change your code like this

```
var App = React.createClass({

  section: function(myObj, parentIndex) {
    return myObj.sectionInfo.map(function(myObj1, index) {
      const key = parentIndex + '.' + index;

      switch(myObj1.elementType) {
        case 1:
          return <Component1 text = {myObj1.text} key={ key } />
        case 2:
          return <Component2 text = {myObj1.text} key={ key } />
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var elements = myPackage.map(function(myObj) {
      return <div>
        { this.section(myObj, index) }
      </div>
    }, this);

    return <div className="App">
     { elements }
    </div>;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 84):

To do a switch case in JSX do it as follow:

```
   {{
    sectionA: (
      <SectionAComponent />
    ),
    sectionB: (
      <SectionBComponent />
    ),
    sectionC: (
      <SectionCComponent />
    ),
    default: (
      <SectionDefaultComponent />
    )
  }[section]}
```

Comment: How does this handle defaults?

Comment: On the last line, you can do 

`[section || sectionC]`

to get better coverage, if you wanted sectionC to be the default.

Comment: @frandroid the default needs to go at the top of the switch. The final match in top-down evaluation is the one that will be returned.

Comment: @Isaac I think a great option would be to add the default after the closing bracket `[section] || <SectionCComponent />`

Comment: @BlakePlumb I think that is not a great option... repeated code?

Comment: [section || sectionC] isn't equivalent to a default - the inner expression will evaluate to sectionC only if section itself is falsy, not [section].  If you need proper default behavior I think you need to use an IIFE.

Comment: I like it but perhaps less performative / more expensive than a switch? wont all 'branches' be evaluated even if only one is used?

Comment: Actually back to this question, the best way for rendering React component depending on a value (type) it's to use the so called "Dot.Notation" https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type, which is far much better than a conditional switch case

Comment: This looks like an "easy to read" solution but I would consider using it because it might causes memory leak. Everytime the render method called it creates an object in the memory and gets the proper value out of it.

Comment: It's not a memory *leak*, just uses more memory than a normal switch.  This is because it is an object literal referencing one of its members by key name.  In theory, all the components in the object would be created, but depending on the interpreter it might get optimised out.

Answer (score 51):

for inline / not created new function ,you can use this way

```
<div>
    {(() => {
        switch (myObj1.elementType) {
            case 'pantulan':
                return <Component1 text = {myObj1.text} key={ key } />
            default :
                null
        }
    })()}
</div>
```

Comment: It is better to create a new function due to the fact that in your case each time that it renders the html it will re-render the function. If you do it in a seperate function then it won't re-render it.

Comment: Does this answer prevent re-renders now that it is wrapped in a function? If so, is this better compared to the above answer? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42438769/4602214)

Answer (score 10):

Recommended way by React: [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type)

```
const components = {
  photo: PhotoStory,
  video: VideoStory
};

function Story(props) {
  // Correct! JSX type can be a capitalized variable.
  const SpecificStory = components[props.storyType];
  return <SpecificStory story={props.story} />;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a return as stated in the [answer by Alexander T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37782919/350933), but I would also recommend adding a key to each of your elements.  React depends on this value for it's diff'ing algorithm, you could do something like:

```
render: function(){
  var elements = myPackage.map(function(myObj, pIndex){
    return myObj.sectionInfo.map(function(myObj1, sIndex){
      var key = pIndex + '.' + sIndex;            
      switch(myObj1.elementType) {
        case 1: return(
          <Component1 key={key} text={myObj1.text}/>
        );
        case 2: return(
          <Component2 key={key} text={myObj1.text}/>
        )
      }
    })
  });
  return(
    <div className="App">
      {elements}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Read here for more info: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children